# Can I fight lower level bosses in Genshin Impact?

Tags: genshin-impact

I have recently completed a quest which has increased my World Level to 4. I didn't realise at the time that this would push all the boss monsters levels up to around 60 to 62.

I only have one lv60 character, and now I need to ascend other heroes I do not have the power to defeat the boss monsters to get the materials I need.

Have I locked myself out of being able to ascend my other characters? The materials I need are from lv30 bosses, but they're all lv62!

My team is this one,
[image: Keqing:60, Chongyun:50, Xingqiu:40, Bennett:49]

I am trying to ascend them all up to 60 now to help, but the materials are proving nearly impossible to obtain

Comment: Your team should be plenty strong enough. Have you levelled up your Talents?

Comment: to further elaborate on @Schism comment, you should at least be able to slowly level up talents and weapons level (since talents books and rare weapon materials come from domains where you can select a difficulty level, if you aren't able to beat the more difficult ones, resort to merge the materials you get from the easier domains to their rarer counterparts at the alchemy bench). Then focus on one boss at time, probably trying to focus on easier ones first (avoid Oceanid for a while, the Cryo Regiwine should be easier).

Comment: Thanks, I have levelled up their talents, but I have not maxed out their weapons or artifacts yet. I'll work on that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the contributors in the comments, I think I have discovered the issue.

Genshin Impact has a lot of things that you need to level up around your characters, rather than just the characters main experience.

1. Character EXP
2. Talent levels (Dependent on their ascension level)
3. Weapon level
4. Artefact levels
5. Character ascension level

Some of my characters were level 40, but had a full set of +0 artefacts on! I think the game assumes you have levelled all these pieces once you reach World Level 4.

Some advice I've researched on YouTube suggests picking one or two characters to focus on in the game, in order to push all these various levels up in sync with your character levels.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question - yes, you can set your World Level back to a lower level if you want. Simply head to the Main Menu, then click the small i next to your World Level. This will give the option to down level the world again until you are ready - though do note that you can only change World Level once every 24 hours. You can head to the same menu to Revert your level once you want to put it back up again.

[image]

Comment: Another thing to consider is that you must also be World Rank 5 (the OP is only World Rank 4)