# I can't Ascend my characters because I can't fight the bosses due to World Level. How can I get the Ascension materials?

Tags: genshin-impact

So, I kinda did an opsie and ended up getting to AR 30 and World Level 3. Now all bosses are between level 45-50 which I'm not powerful enough to fight.

Because of this, I got stuck in a Catch-22 where I need to defeat bosses to level up my characters, but I can't defeat those bosses because my character levels not enough.

How can I get ascension materials considering that I can't defeat the bosses that drop them?

Comment: What level are your characters now?

Comment: You can try requesting help in coop or upgrade other assets - character talents? weapons or artifacts. Those are farmable from domain, and you can always pick lvl in those

Comment: Related: [Can I fight lower level bosses in Genshin Impact?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/390367/124566)